# How to check for both POST and GET data whilst using filter_input?

Tags: php, post, optimization, get, filter-input

I'm wondering if it's possible to get a variable whether it is in POST or GET and then use filter_input() to sanitize it.

At first I thought that `$var = filter_input(INPUT_POST | INPUT_GET, "var", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` might work, however it doesn't and the PHP manual states you can only pass one type of input.

I also tried `INPUT_REQUEST`, which strangely didn't work. The function recognises it (i.e. it doesn't throw up an error saying I've put something wrong in $input), yet it won't get any code. And yes, I know not to use `INPUT_REQUEST` in a live environment, I was just purely testing to see if it would work.

Currently I do the following:

```
$var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "var", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if(!$var) $var = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "var", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

however with many things in PHP, there is often simpler way that will do it all for me in one command. I'm wondering if that is the case here, can I combine them into one check? I performed a cursory search on Google and couldn't even find any references to anyone trying this before, let alone a solution, so now I turn to you good folks.

Comment: For what purpose you want to "sanitize" your string?

Comment: To make sure that no malicious code has been entered in a GET variable, or in the case of a POST someone hasn't tampered with the form (it'd most likely be a hidden variable) and placed something malicious there.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php - as it is said, the first param is one of the constants, no array, no || clause. If you want to do it with one line, you have to make a user-function that accepts i.e. array, foreaches and sets all the elements as first param. However, it seems bad practice, since you do not really know what your input is.

Comment: Define "malicious code". What certain code you are talking about?

Comment: Google malicious PHP code and take your pick.

Comment: I tried to make a user defined function, but them saw in the comments of the function there are a lot of already done by people, check down the comments in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

It's considered bad practice if you don't know whether your input is in `GET` or `POST`. You should always know and not just randomly accept whatever.

Comment: Mostly I'd agree with that, and I do generally stick to one or the other. I do occasionally arise at a situation though where I post data to a page from a form, but also like the user to be able to save the link with the variable available it's easier to use both POST and GET types.

Comment: So you're saying _"I know that my use-case is bad but I would still like it to be supported"_.

Comment: Not at all, I'm arguing that in most cases it's bad practise, though, as with most things, there are exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 2):

I think there isn't a better approach than making a custom function with the code you already mentioned:

```
function getPostOrGet($name) {

  $var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  if(!$var) $var = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  return $var;

}
```

And if you think in it is normal you can't use the `|` operator because then what happened if it's defined in both.

Also note that, as it's a bad practice, it doesn't have an "easy" way of doing it. So use a custom function if you really need it, and use only the correct input type if you can.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the party. I had the same probem. My solution for this case is a approch like this:

```
$data = array_merge(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST), filter_input_array(INPUT_GET));
$var = $data["var"];
```

If you need to sanitize before use the options from filter_input_array: http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input-array.php

For example:

```
$args = array(
    'var'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
);
```

And combined:

```
$data = array_merge(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args), filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, $args));
$var = $data["var"];
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i read you could change the value `POST` in your form to `GET` - that way you only need to accept `GET` - not sure if i understood it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you **sanitize properly** your input, I would personally test the result of `filtre_input` for `null`, because the `if(!$var)` condition could be triggered by a falsy but existing value like `0`.

For instance :

```
function getLatitude($name) {
  $var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'latitude', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
  if($var === null){
      $var = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'latitude', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
  }
  return $var;
}
```

With the usual `!$var` condition and `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT`, you will get a `null` value instead of `0`.

Answer (score -1):

Old topic, but for some cases it can be handy

```
$var = filter_var($_REQUEST['var'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
```

Comment: `$_REQEUST` also includes cookies, so someone could set a cookie called `var` with whatever input and it'd match. Also, it will error if there is no POST, GET or COOKIE matching `var`.

Comment: @Styphon true, but a get or post can also have any kind of input. This solution won't work in all cases if you have get post and cookies with the same name. But as I said, in some cases this can just be handy and easy/.